# Toggle One And Off - JavaScript - Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I am an Audio Engineer and just started JavaScript and HTML5, Specifically WEB Audio API.

I have this oscillator code which is connected to destination(output).
here is the code

I want to have a buttons to connect and disconnect the oscillator to destination
I managed to make it start but I can't disconnect it.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        //creating the context
        context = new webkitAudioContext(); //allways the first code for audio API
        function osc1(frequency){ // Creating a function that has an oscillator going to gainNode and then going to the destination

            //creating AudioNodes and AudioParams

            //creating OscillatorNode
            var oscillator = context.createOscillator(); //creating Node's as Variables
            oscillator.type = 0; //0 is a sine wave
            oscillator.noteOn(0); // turning on the oscillator
            oscillator.frequency.value = frequency;// telling that frequency in () of the function equals to what


            //creating GainNode
            var gain = context.createGainNode(); // creating the Gain node
            gain.gain.value = 1; // setting up the value for gain node


            //Making the connections
            oscillator.connect(gain); // connecting oscillator to gain
            gain.connect(context.destination); // connecting gain to destination (speakers)
        }; // now we have a function called osc1(we can put frequency in here) then we can re call


    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" value="on"  onClick="osc1(500);" />

</body>

</html>
```

I know that the code for disconnecting it is `oscillator.disconnect();`, but I don't know how to to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want declare the oscillator variable outside the function:

```
var context = new webkitAudioContext();
var oscillator = context.createOscillator();
function osc1(frequency){
  var button = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  if (button.value === 'off') {
    button.value = 'on';
    oscillator.disconnect();
  } else {
    button.value = 'off';
    // same as your original code (connect, noteOn...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on this too.

You do oscillator.disconnect(0) where zero represents the output number.

I think that means if you connect the oscillator to a gain node and a filter node separately, gain would be disconnect(0) and filter would be disconnect(1).

I think keeping track of what outputs are what is our job, since there doesn't look like a built in way.

I would hope the spec changes so that we can pass disconnect() the actual node we want disconnected.

Comment: i guess instead of source.disconnect() is better to use source.stop() if you want to keep the nodes connected.

Comment: I've noticed noteOff() (which is now stop()?) decrements the audioContext.activeSource which is good, but since you can't restart once you've stopped having the connected nodes seems pointless.

Answer (score 0):

It's been mentioned already, but you need to expose the `oscillator` variable (possibly to the global scope) so that your off function can disconnect it (make sure you don't redeclare the `oscillator` variable inside the `onclick` handler).

Here's a working example: http://jsbin.com/iwetiy/1/edit